# Entity Framework Property HasConversion with Arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So storing complex objects in database, I am converting the object to JSON string by serializing the object. For reading it back as an object, JSON deserialize is applied. So far everything is working fine.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
     .Property(e => e.MyAddress)
     .HasConversion(
        x => FromAddress(x),
        x => ToAddress(x)
   );
```

```
protected Address ToAddress(string address)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Address>(address, null);
}

protected string FromAddress(Address address)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(address, null);
}
```

My question is, is there any way possible I can pass another argument in my converter from the Entity Framework for deserialization? I require this because the `Address` model will actually be 3 types. All inheriting from the `BaseAddress` class. During deserialization, I need to depend on another field from the same table that will help it determine to which Child model it has to deserialize it to.

```
protected Address ToAddress(string address, int type)
{
    if(type == 1)
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AddressOne>(address, null);
    else if (type == 2)
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AddressTwo>(address, null);
    else if (type == 3)
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AddressThree>(address, null);
    else
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Address>(address, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by design because EF doesn't allow you pass any additional parameters to the HasConversion delegates.

This is really begging for re-design to normalize and split the address data into a separate table or tables. You could use a single table and use table-per-hierarchy (TPH), or multiple tables - 1 for each address type - and use table-per-type (TPT). TPH is available in both EF6 and EFCore, but TPT is only available in EF6 at the moment.

[Here](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/10/27/efcore_tph/) is a practical implementation example of TPH.

Please see [Microsoft docs on EF Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).